# Include module in view rendered using ActionView::Base.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am rendering a view using ActionView::Base

```
ActionView::Base.new('app/views', { json: Jbuilder.new }).render(file: "some/view"})
```

**I would like to extract a few helper methods currently living inside this view to a module and include that module in the view**. I think I need to set a controller class and pass it to ActionView::Base.new as an argument but have been unable to do so.

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. Can you please explain why you need to use `ActionView` instances like that? You tagged your question with 'ruby-on-rails', I wonder what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by creating a class which inherits from ActionView::Base and including whatever I wanted in there.

```
class SomeViewTemplate < ActionView::Base
  include MyHelper

  def some_method
     # any methods you'd like
  end
end
```

Then I'd instantiate an ActionView::Base class.

```
my_view = SpiltTestTemplate.new('app/views', { json: Jbuilder.new }).render(file: "some/view"})
```

You'll have access to any helper methods in `MyHelper`inside this my_view (also the `some_method` method).